# JSON, post using jquery ajax is returning fail

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have below code, In this I want to convert the entire form to JSON and post it using jquery AJAX. My problem is, its getting into the Servlet and I can get the values in request.getParameter, but still I am getting ajax fail. Once I will get the response I want to display the returned response and display it on the same page. Please help me finding what is wrong. I have searched a lot but couldnt link it to right ans. Many Many Thanks in Advance!!

Here my code. ShowHideDiv_ajax.html

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#form_submit').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var form = $("#myform");
      var json = ConvertFormToJSON(form);
      $("#results").text(JSON.stringify(json)  );

      $.ajax({
        url: 'AjaxServlet',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: json,
        success: function( response ) {
          //I want to use this response  to be displayed on the same page.
          alert('success');
        },
        error: function() { // if error occured
          alert('fail:');
        }
      });

      return false;
    });

    function ConvertFormToJSON(form){
      var array = form.serializeArray();
      var json = {};
      $.each(array, function() {
        //alert('this.name='+this.name+'this.value='+this.value);
        if (json[this.name] !== undefined) {
          if (!json[this.name].push) {
            json[this.name] = [json[this.name]];
          }
          jsono[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
          json[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
      });
      return json;
    }
   });     
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="ajax_form" id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="AjaxServlet" >
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><div id="error" class="error"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Enter your name : </td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="name" name="firstname"><br/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Education : </td>
        <td> <input type="text" id="education" name="edu"><br/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><div id="info" class="success"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <p><tt id="results"></tt></p>
  <p><tt id="results1"></tt></p>
  <input class="ajax_button" type="submit" value="Submit"  id="form_submit" name="form_submit">
</body>
```

And Servelt AjaxServlet.java:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  System.out.println("in post ajaxservlet");
  try {
    String fn, ed=null;
    fn = request.getParameter("firstname");
    ed = request.getParameter("edu");
    System.out.println("receieved data:"+fn+ed);
    if(request.getParameter("firstname").toString()!=null){
      fn="Hello User";
    }

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
    out.write(fn);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("data posted");
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax call has dataType set to json, which means it expects json to be returned.  However, all that's being returned is "Hello User".  This isn't json and is probably causing the error.  I would try using a dataType of html and in your Java method use setContentType("text/html") instead of "text/json"

Comment: Thanks!! It's working after i changed what you have suggested.

Comment: I had a similar error using .NET Web Api when I copy/pasted an existing ajax POST call (which contained the dataType:json option) and used it on a void [HttpPost] method. After a half day of looking what went wrong , this pointed me in the right direction. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The right contenty type for json is:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
```

Try to change your code and test again.